# Как переопределить метод equals для использовании в ArrayList?

Tags: java, equals

Есть такой код

```
    class User{
       private String name;
       public User(String name){this.name = name;}
       public String getName() {
           return this.name;
       }
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if(obj instanceof String){
               return obj.equals(this.getName());
           }
           return super.equals(obj);
       }
    }
```

Я пытаюсь провернуть такую операцию.

```
ArrayList<User>.contains(String)
```

Но результат выполнения никакой. Даже при наличии заведомо верных данных не находит совпадений.

Как корректно переопределить метод equals()?

Comment: вы также должны hashCode определить

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, а зачем массиву хэш? Он же не словарь.

Comment: Тут несколько вариантов... 1,унаследоваться от ArrayList и переписать метод contains так, как вам надо. 2. проходить циклом по вашей коллекции и сравнивать соответсвующие поля с помощью equals. 3.если у вас нет повторяющихся элементов, то переопределить методы hashCode  и equals, заменить ArrayList на  Set, какой из них уже зависит от потребностей. 3 вариант предпочтительней , разумеется, нужны уникальные элементы. цикл сделать можно, если размер коллекции заведомо невелик. первый способ сложно оценить, тут все в ваших руках

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Как раз с помощью contains  я хотел избежать foreach, ради производительности. Повторы есть. Так что сделаю всё-таки с помощью цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the Source, Luke](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use%20the%20Source%2C%20Luke) - смотрите исходники `ArrayList`

```
public class java.util.ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
     implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {

//blah-blah

public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}

public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Отсюда следует, что идет сравнение не `User.equals(String)`, а `String.equals(User)`...

То есть вам надо создать свой `class MyArrayList<> extends ArrayList<>`, в котором операция `contains()` переопределена так как надо вам.