# Как осуществить проверку на наличие объекта в списке java?

Tags: java, list

У меня есть список `medications` объектов класса `Medication`.

Я пытаюсь добавить новый объект в этот список, но не хочу, чтобы оне добавлялся, если там такой объект уже есть:

```
public void addMedication(Medication medication) {
    if (medications.contains(medication)) {
        System.out.println("Данный медикамент уже присутствует в системе!");
    } else {medications.add(medication);}
}
```

Сам класс выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class Medication implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String pharmaceuticalNumber;
    private int unitNumber;
}
```

Сериализацию я использую лишь для хранения в базе данных.
На текущий момент, когда я пытаюсь добавить медикамент с уже существующим инвентарным номером (`pharmaceuticalNumber`), у меня получается добавить.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это получается из-за наличия serialVersionUID, и если я хочу проверять на наличие, то я должен в цикле обойти весь список и сверить инвентарные номера у всех объектов? Или есть вариант попроще?

UPD. Предвосхищая встречные вопросы: я придумал только такой вариант проверки, но мне кажется, что он слишком громоздкий:

```
private boolean checkContains(List<Medication> medications, Medication medication) {
    for (Medication med: medications) {
        if (med.getPharmaceuticalNumber().equals(medication.getPharmaceuticalNumber())) {
            return  true;
        }
    }
    return  false;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как переопределить метод equals для использовании в ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787333/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-equals-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-arraylist)

Comment: Нет, потому что ответом на мой вопрос является "переопределить equals для класса", а по ссылке автор уже догадался, до такой возможности и возникли вопросы к реализации. Извините, но тот вопрос даже через гугл не найти по постановке задачи как у меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `contains()` работает на основе метода `equals()`. Если в списке находится элемент, который по методу `equals()` равен переданному объекту, то `contains()` вернёт `true`.

Вы не переопределяете метод `equals()` в классе `Medication`, соответственно, берётся его реализация по умолчанию, а она представляет собой простое сравнение ссылок. Поэтому неудивительно, что в список можно добавить любой новый объект.

Чтобы проверка работала так, как вы хотите, вам нужно переопределить метод `equals()`. В общем случае он должен содержать все поля объекта за некоторыми исключениями, хотя если есть какой-нибудь айдишник, то теоретически можно опираться только на него - это как раз ваш случай. В переопределённом методе `equals()` вы можете сравнивать только поля `pharmaceuticalNumber`.

Вот пример такого метода:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Medication medication)) {
        return false;
    }
    return pharmaceuticalNumber.equals(medication.pharmaceuticalNumber);
}
```

Переопределяя метод `equals()`, не забывайте также переопределять метод `hashCode()`. Его реализация, согласованная с приведённым выше методом `equals()`, может выглядеть так:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(pharmaceuticalNumber);
}
```